# Plot a 5 dimensional quantity

Tags: plotting

I have to plot a function of four angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ all of which vary from 0 to $\pi$; the function is simply:

```
Cos[α] Cos[β] + Cos[γ] Cos[δ]
```

I am thinking of something like the plot shown in [this](https://epic-code.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MCMC.html) site, with the projection on one coordinate and a `ContourPlot` between the two, something similar to the plots in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164667/8822) answer. If I had a 3D function I could use for example `PointOfView` to project on one coordinate, but I have a 5D quantity and I am lost.

I am using version 10.0

Comment: Parallel coordinates can be a mechanism to show higher dimension data. It all depends on the data and what you are trying to see. Here's a parallel coordinates solution. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207054/how-to-plot-parallel-coordinates

Comment: Perhaps the use of Quanterions would be helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everywhere below I use a rescaled by Pi version with variable ranges $[0,1]$ -- it easier to understand it on the plots:

```
Cos[Pi a]Cos[Pi b]+Cos[Pi g]Cos[Pi d]
```

### 3D + color + tabulation

[image]

You can make usage of `DensityPlot3D` that gives you 4D plotting (3 axes and 4th color variable) and then run remaining 5th variable through a range of values. This code will give you the top image (explore options of `DensityPlot3D` to adapt to your needs):

```
Multicolumn[
Table[
DensityPlot3D[
    Cos[Pi a]Cos[Pi b]+Cos[Pi g]Cos[Pi d],
    {a,0,1},{b,0,1},{g,0,1},
    PlotLabel->"d = Pi*"<>ToString[N[d,2]],
    ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap",
    PlotTheme->"Detailed",
    PlotLegends->None],
{d,0,1,1/15}]
,4]
```

### 3D + color + tabulation

[image]

This one is a bit unorthodox, but I just love the look of it.

```
Multicolumn[
Table[
    SliceContourPlot3D
        [Cos[Pi a]Cos[Pi b]+Cos[Pi g]Cos[Pi d],
        {"CenterCutSphere",Pi/2,0},
        {a,0,1},{b,0,1},{g,0,1},
        ViewPoint->{2.4,-0.6,2.3},
        Boxed->False,
        Axes->False,
        Contours->15,
        Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True}],
{d,0,1,1/8}],
4]
```

### 3D + color + tabulation

[image]

One more take on this...

```
Multicolumn[
Table[
    SliceContourPlot3D
        [Cos[Pi a]Cos[Pi b]+Cos[Pi g]Cos[Pi d],
        {"ZStackedPlanes",4},
        {a,0,1},{b,0,1},{g,0,1},
        RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},x<1/2||y>1/2],
        Contours->15,
        PlotTheme->"Detailed",
        PlotLegends->False,
        Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True}],
{d,0,1,1/8}],
4]
```

### 3D + multi-surface + animation

[image]

Alternatively you can use Plot3D surface for 3D, table of surfaces for the 4th, and animation for the 5th parameter. Here is the code for the animation above:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot3D[
    Table[Cos[Pi a]Cos[Pi b]+Cos[Pi g]Cos[Pi d],{b,0,1,1/2}],
    {a,0,1},{g,0,1},
    PlotPoints->15,
    SphericalRegion->True,
    ImageSize->{400,400},
    Mesh->10,
    MeshStyle->Opacity[.5],
    BoxRatios->1,
    ColorFunction->"Rainbow",
    AxesLabel->{a,g,f}],
{d,0,1}]
```

Comment: Perhaps the 5th dimension could be the opacity? or the saturation of the color? 3-space dimensions, 1 hue, 1 opacity/saturation?

Comment: @SHuisman nice idea but ...actually I am not sure how to pass the 5th one to anything internal of a plot. For instance `ColorFunction` will take only x,y,z,f values and the 5th one is just a parameter --- not sure how to pass it inside of a plot. Any ideas?

Comment: What is f is just a list, or complex number?

Comment: @SHuisman f is the value of a function fed into a plotting function. in [dcos](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) in details look at the first section.

Comment: Thanks it is what I was looking for.